# Angular SSR error - Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I get below error in my Angular project when I serve the SSR prod build. This happened after I upgraded Angular from 16.0 to 16.1 and is gone when I revert back. What could be the issue?

```
TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
    at insertElement (/angular/dist/server/main.js:1:479144)
    at insertHTMLElement (/angular/dist/server/main.js:1:478866)
    at before_head_mode (/angular/dist/server/main.js:1:516818)
    at HTMLParser.htmlparser.insertToken (/angular/dist/server/main.js:1:477890)
    at emitSimpleTag (/angular/dist/server/main.js:1:483071)
    at data_state (/angular/dist/server/main.js:1:483109)
    at scanChars (/angular/dist/server/main.js:1:474652)
    at Object.parse (/angular/server/main.js:1:472719)
    at exports2.createDocument (/angular/server/main.js:1:710626)
    at exports2.createWindow (/angular/dist/server/main.js:1:711129)
```

ng version below:-
[image]

**Update** - I saw a related issue from some time back - [Angular universal with Domino : Getting Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56903846/angular-universal-with-domino-getting-right-hand-side-of-instanceof-is-not-a)
I saw a comment in that issue which say -
`there's a fork of domino with a fix(https://www.npmjs.com/package/domino-ext). See issue 146 (https://github.com/fgnass/domino/issues/146) on domino for more discussion.`

Comment: Which Node version do you use?

Comment: My node version is v18.16.0

Comment: I have the same problem - strangely it only seems to occur in some projects though. The frontend of my current project works just fine, but the backend, which is compiled from almost the same sources, just doesn't.

Comment: Did some more testing. It actually works up to Angular 16.1.1

Node: 18.16.1
Package Manager: pnpm 8.6.6
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 16.1.1
... animations, cdk, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
... forms, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router

Package Version
@angular-devkit/architect 0.1601.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular 16.1.1
@angular-devkit/core 16.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics 16.1.1
@nguniversal/builders 16.1.1
@nguniversal/express-engine 16.1.1
@schematics/angular 16.1.1
rxjs 7.8.1
typescript 5.1.6

Comment: if you use the 'domino' to create for instance window or document object, remove this package and find some alternative. You may try https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-browser

Comment: I use domino package for SSR dom emulation, is there any reason why domino is not working with 16.1?

Comment: Today I converted app (v16.2.0) to SSR and to fix the window undefined I added domino and when I tried to serve ssr got the same error. @KamS have you tried mock-browser, if it's working please share the example server.ts with us

Answer (score 4):

The option of disable optimization is not valid for production environments because you will have a poor performance.

By now I think easy fix is downgrade to:    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.1.1" instead of 16.1.4

I have created a issue in angular-cli repository
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/25529

Comment: In my case, downgrading the '@angular-devkit/build-angular' package to  "^16.1.1" doesn't solve the problem, but I see that there is considering an issue with the 'domino' package.

Answer (score 1):

My issue related to the `domino` package, so I removed it and had to wrap all instances of `document`, `window`, ect... in a platform check.

1. remove the `domino` package from package.json
2. `rm -rf node_modules`
3. `rm -rf package-lock.json`
4. `npm i`
5. Wrap all instances of DOM objects, such as `window` and `document`
   EX:

```
import { PLATFORM_ID, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

export class SomeClass {
constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    if(isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
     someFunction()
    }

  }

someFunction() {
return window.location;
}

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

In package.json I have changed
"domino": "2.1.6",
to

"domino": "https://github.com/ndr/domino.git#87c3ef9d60965ded1e713893c3b7c32a421958b1",

Linked domino package to own fork, but with a little workaround on the line that cause error. And it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

My solution.

Check the file **Angular.json** and change the value of  **server.options.optimization**  to *false*.  I don't know exactly where is the problem, although it solves this problem in my project.

I hope it helps you.