# Angular 16 SSR throws TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-universal, server-rendering

I was just trying to update my angular application from version 15 to 16. Everything works with angular. Even it makes build for angular universal with no error. But when I try to serve with `npm run serve:ssr` it throws error

[image]

> TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object

Initially I thought it could be some error in my code but I remove entire code and keep only app component with a simple heading. It still throws same error.

**server.ts**

```
import { enableProdMode } from "@angular/core";
(global as any).WebSocket = require('ws');
(global as any).XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');


import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/project-name/browser');
const template = fs.readFileSync(path.join(distFolder, 'index.html')).toString();
const win = domino.createWindow(template.toString());
global['window'] = win;
global['document'] = win.document;
global['DOMTokenList'] = win.DOMTokenList;
global['Node'] = win.Node;
global['Text'] = win.Text;
global['HTMLElement'] = win.HTMLElement;
global['navigator'] = win.navigator;
global['getComputedStyle'] = win.getComputedStyle;

// (global as any).self = {fetch: require('node-fetch')};

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';


// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/project-name/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

   // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/main/modules/express-engine)
   server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.get('/env', (req, res) => {
    res.json(process.env);
  })
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on https://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: This issue is caused by domino.  More info on this link.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56903846/angular-universal-with-domino-getting-right-hand-side-of-instanceof-is-not-a

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got work around with the help of [temperoary forked extension for domino](https://www.npmjs.com/package/domino-ext)

1. Install domino ext. `npm install domino-ext`.
2. Replace `domino` with `domino-ext` in `server.ts` file.

```
const domino = require('domino');
```

Replace with

```
const domino = require('domino-ext');
```

Now make build and serve, it will worked fine afterwards.

[Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68615836/1682525)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's something in my configuration but when I used:

```js
import { createWindow } from 'domino-ext';
```

I got this error:

> /node_modules/domino-ext/lib/index.d.ts' is not a module.

Changing the module name from `domino` to `domino-ext` resolved the issue:

```js
declare module "domino-ext" {
  function createDOMImplementation(): DOMImplementation;
  function createDocument(html?: string, force?: boolean): Document;
  function createWindow(html?: string, address?: string): Window;
}
```